# Typescript extract type of all unique leaf values of an object

Tags: typescript

I have a constant which is a tree holding unique keys as its leaves, e.g.:

```
const Tree = {
  Branch1: {
    Leaf1: '1'
    SubBranch1: {
      SubLeaf: '11'
    },
    ...
  },
  Branch2: {
    Leaf2: '2'
    SubBranch2: {
      SubLeaf: '21'
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

I would like to create a generic type `Leaves<typeof Tree>` that would be a list of all of the leaf values, i.e. `'1' | '11' | '2' | '21' ...`. The issue is that I cannot find any examples of how I can effectively reduce a tree of objects to their keys or anything of the sort.

Comment: you need to specify what is a leaf (I imagine in this case it's a `${number}` and write a recursive type that traverses the tree

Comment: @geoffrey leaves are ultimately unique strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```ts
const Tree = {
  Branch1: {
    Leaf1: '1',
    SubBranch1: {
      SubLeaf: '11'
    }
  },
  Branch2: {
    Leaf2: '2',
    SubBranch2: {
      SubLeaf: '21'
    }
  }
} as const;

type Leaves<T, L0 = T[keyof T]> = L0 extends Record<string, any> ? Leaves<L0> : L0;

let l: Leaves<typeof Tree>
// ^?let l: "1" | "11" | "2" | "21"
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/NarPom)

The only thing worth explaining is the fact that the type parameter `L0` may be a conditional type (if there are multiple keys) so in that case it works as a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types).

Also, using `as const` ([const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)) when defining the constant ensures its type is the most specific case, otherwise the leaves types would have been just `string`.

**Note**: edited to remove unnecessary code. The original [playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4n2AN) might still be useful to understand how it works.

Comment: Took me a minute, but then it clicked how it works, thanks for the explanation.